# ¿Cómo reducir el peso de un programa en Python?

Tags: python

hice un programa en Python y utilizo la librería de "easyocr" la cual es demasiado pesada, es por ésta librería que mi programa queda MUY PESADO (1gb) al ser empaquetado en un ejecutable.
Es muy sencillo lo que hace el programa, y es muy poco lo que utilizo de dicha librería, pero al parecer se incluye completa.

¿Existe algún modo de "optimizar" esto? ¿Hay alguna solución? ¿Quizás otra manera que no sea haciendo un ejecutable?

Destaco que el programa es para "comercializarlo" por lo tanto me es contraproducente que pese tanto.

¡Saludos y mil gracias!

Comment: puedes hacerlo usando un [spec file](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#:~:text=The%20spec%20file%20tells%20PyInstaller,contents%20of%20the%20spec%20file.) que te permite incluir exactamente lo que deseas

Comment: @Bryro pero usando eso se puede incluir solo las funciones que utilice y no todo el modulo?

Answer (score 0):

De por si ya sabemos que esa librería (y sus sublibrerías) ocupa mucho espacio
Igual te dejo un par de opciones:

1. Decirle al programa con el que creás el ejecutable que no te agregue las librerías del easyOCR, y después pedirle al usuario que se la descargue aparte (pero tendrías que decirle a tu script donde buscar las librerías  y eso puede ser un embole)
2. Separar tu app en front y back end, el backend (con el easyocr y todo ese choclo) lo subís a un server, con el front creás la app que tiene la interfaz y llama al backend.